# Can I make a “nice mock” with Sinon.JS?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, sinon

Here’s a hypothetical Mocha test that verifies that `ObjectUser#useObject` calls `Object#callMe`.

```
describe('ObjectUser', function() {
  describe('#useObject', function() {
    it('calls `callMe`, maybe', function(done) {

      var objectMock = { callMe: sinon.spy() };
      new ObjectUser().useObject(objectMock).done(function() {
        expect(objectMock.test).to.have.been.calledOnce
        done();
      });

    });
  });
});
```

In this test, I create a mock object, replacing the method I want to test with a Sinon.JS spy; I pass the mock into the method that I'm testing; and I verify that the spy was called once using `chai-sinon`.

However, the test fails with a `TypeError` when `ObjectUser#useObject` tries to call a method on `object` (let’s call it `Object#log`) that’s undefined in my mock.

Is there a convenient way to make a “nice mock” that, e.g., replaces `undefined` methods with `function() {}` to avoid tests failing with `TypeError`s without

1. having to pollute the tests themselves with irrelevant implementation details? or
2. having to pollute the calling code with `undefined` checks before the calls are made?

Comment: Personally, I don't consider "properly" defining a mocked/stubbed object as "polluting" the test with "irrelevant implementation details". If you don't want the mock details to appear in the actual test file, you can always define them elsewhere and require it as needed.